# Skip first 3 bytes of a file

Tags: shell, text-processing, aix, ksh

I am using AIX 6.1 ksh shell.

I want to use one liner to do something like this:

```
cat A_FILE | skip-first-3-bytes-of-the-file
```

I want to skip the first 3 bytes of the first line; is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Old school — you could use `dd`:

```
dd if=A_FILE bs=1 skip=3
```

The input file is `A_FILE`, the block size is 1 character (byte), skip the first 3 'blocks' (bytes).  (With some variants of `dd` such as GNU `dd`, you could use `bs=1c` here — and alternatives like `bs=1k` to read in blocks of 1 kilobyte in other circumstances.  The `dd` on AIX does not support this, it seems; the BSD (macOS Sierra) variant doesn't support `c` but does support `k`, `m`, `g`, etc.)

There are other ways to achieve the same result, too:

```
sed '1s/^...//' A_FILE
```

This works if there are 3 or more characters on the first line.

```
tail -c +4 A_FILE
```

And you could use Perl, Python and so on too.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both the sed and the tail commands work in AIX 6.1.  For the dd command, it should be `dd if=A_FILE bs=1 skip=3` in AIX 6.1

Comment: You may want to use standard input as such cat A_FILE | tail -c +4 with gnu.

Comment: Warning: using `dd` like this will slow down the whole process by several orders of magnitude. `bs=1` sets the block size to a single byte which prevents efficient file IO. Switching the parameters, e.g. `bs=3 skip=1` helps a little bit, but using `tail` is much more efficient anyway. I did not test `sed` for speed.

Answer (score 26):

Instead of using `cat` you can use `tail` as such:

```
tail -c +4 FILE
```

This will print out the entire file except for the first 3 bytes. Consult `man tail` for more information.

Comment: Don't know about AIX, but on Solaris you must use `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail`, at least on my machine.  Good tip nonetheless!

Comment: @BobDuell It's hard to post something that is compatible with every OS.

Comment: Yes, it works in AIX 6.1

Comment: @AlvinSIU Good to know.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better choice for working with large files with a tiny amount of garbage at the beginning.  I used `dd` over an ssh connection to get a file image and I needed to remove the "[sudo] password for X:" at the beginning of the resulting file.

Answer (score 1):

If one has Python on their system, one can use small python script to take advantage of `seek()` function to start reading at the nth byte like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1],'rb') as fd:
    fd.seek(int(sys.argv[2]))
    for line in fd:
        print(line.decode().strip())
```

And usage would be like so:

```
$ ./skip_bytes.py input.txt 3
```

Note that byte count starts at 0 (thus first byte is actually index 0), thus by specifying 3 we're effectively positioning the reading to start at 3+1=4th byte

Answer (score 0):

I needed to recently do something similar.  I was helping with a field support issue and needed to let a technician see real time plots as they were making changes. The data is in a binary log that grows throughout the day. I have software that can parse and plot the data from logs, but it is currently not real time.  What I did was capture the size of the log before I started processing the data, then went into a loop that would process the data and each pass create a new file with the bytes of the file that had not yet been processed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# I named this little script hackjob.sh
# The purpose of this is to process an input file and load the results into
# a database. The file is constantly being update, so this runs in a loop
# and every pass it creates a new temp file with bytes that have not yet been
# processed.  It runs about 15 seconds behind real time so it's
# pseudo real time.  This will eventually be replaced by a real time
# queue based version, but this does work and surprisingly well actually.

set -x

# Current data in YYYYMMDD fomat
DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

INPUT_PATH=/path/to/my/data
IFILE1=${INPUT_PATH}/${DATE}_my_input_file.dat

OUTPUT_PATH=/tmp
OFILE1=${OUTPUT_PATH}/${DATE}_my_input_file.dat

# Capture the size of the original file
SIZE1=`ls -l ${IFILE1} | awk '{print $5}'`

# Copy the original file to /tmp
cp ${IFILE1} ${OFILE1}

while :
do
    sleep 5

    # process_my_data.py ${OFILE1}
    rm ${OFILE1}
    # Copy IFILE1 to OFILE1 minus skipping the amount of data already processed
    dd skip=${SIZE1} bs=1 if=${IFILE1} of=${OFILE1}
    # Update the size of the input file
    SIZE1=`ls -l ${IFILE1} | awk '{print $5}'`

    echo

    DATE=`date +%Y%m%d`

done
```

Comment: If only because I'm in that kind of mood, and don't like coding against the output of `ls`; have you considered using `stat -c'%s' "${IFILE}"` instead of that `ls|awk` combo?  That is, assuming GNU coreutils...